# How to link local image to string in js

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm building a image module for my react app and i found this on the [internet](https://reactjsexample.com/an-image-lightbox-component-for-reactjs/) and it works great but i cant figure out how to link local images in there not from google(url) or wiki(url) but from my local img folder thanks for help

```
import Lightbox from 'react-lightbox-component';
const App = () => (


<div>
    <Lightbox images={
      [
        {
          src: 'some image url',
          title: 'image title',
          description: 'image description'
        }
      ]
    }/>
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import ImageSrc from "../path/to/your/image";


<Lightbox images={
  [
    {
      src: {ImageSrc},
      title: 'image title',
      description: 'image description'
    }
  ]
}/>
```

You need to navigate from your current folder correctly

`../`   - goes back a folder
`/`   - goes forward a folder

Build out a path that references the location of the image.

Here is my subpage:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import{
  Link
} from 'react-router-dom';
import Lightbox from 'react-lightbox-component';

//import img
import img1 from'../../assets/img/vizualizacie/vizualizacie1.jpeg';
import img2 from'../../assets/img/vizualizacie/vizualizacie2.jpeg';
import img3 from'../../assets/img/vizualizacie/vizualizacie3.jpeg';
import img4 from'../../assets/img/vizualizacie/vizualizacie4.jpeg';



class Vizualizacie extends Component{




  render() {



    return (

    <div className="Vizualizacie" >

      <div className="sekcia1">

        <h1>Vizualizácie</h1>

      </div>

      <div className="sekcia2">

        <h2>Naša Tvorba</h2>
        <p>
          Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia lorem ipsum dolor sit amet dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit
        </p>

      </div>

        <Lightbox className="sekcia3" images={ [
          {
            src: {img1},
            title: 'Ropy pahoehoe',
            description: 'By Tari Noelani Mattox. Licensed under Public Domain via Commons'
          },
          {
            src: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/73/Pyroclastic_flows_at_Mayon_Volcano.jpg',
            title: 'Pyroclastic flows at Mayon Volcano',
            description: 'By C.G. Newhall. Licensed under Public Domain via Commons'
          },
          {
            src: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f3/Okataina.jpg',
            title: 'Okataina',
            description: 'By Richard Waitt. Licensed under Public Domain via Commons'
          },
          {
            src: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f3/Okataina.jpg',
            title: 'Okataina',
            description: 'By Richard Waitt. Licensed under Public Domain via Commons'
          }
        ] }/>




    </div>






    );
  }
}

export default Vizualizacie;
```

And here is my lightbox.jsx component:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Container from './Container';
import BodyPortal from './BodyPortal';
import './Lightbox.css'

import img1 from'./../../../assets/img/vizualizacie/vizualizacie1.jpeg';

export default class Lightbox extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.toggleLightbox = this.toggleLightbox.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      showLightbox: false,
      selectedImage: 0
    };
  }

  toggleLightbox(idx) {
    this.setState({
      showLightbox: !this.state.showLightbox,
      selectedImage: idx
    });
  }

  render() {
    let props = this.props;
    let images = props.images.map((image, idx) => {
      return props.renderImageFunc.call(
        this,
        idx,
        image,
        this.toggleLightbox,
        props.thumbnailWidth,
        props.thumbnailHeight
      );
    });
    let container;
    if (this.state.showLightbox)
      container = (
        <BodyPortal>
          <Container
            {...this.props}
            toggleLightbox={this.toggleLightbox}
            selectedImage={this.state.selectedImage}
          />
        </BodyPortal>
      )

    return (
      <div className='lightbox-container'>
        {images}
        {container}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

Lightbox.defaultProps = {
  showImageModifiers: true,
  thumbnailWidth: '80px',
  thumbnailHeight: '80px',
  renderImageFunc: (idx, image, toggleLightbox, width, height) => {
    return (
      <img
        key={idx}
        src={ !!image.thumbnail ? image.thumbnail : image.src  }
        className='lightbox-img-thumbnail'
        style={{width: width, height: height}}
        alt={image.title}
        onClick={toggleLightbox.bind(null, idx)} />
    )
  }
}

Lightbox.propTypes = {
  images: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
    src: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    title: PropTypes.string,
    description: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.string, PropTypes.object]),
    thumbnail: PropTypes.string
  })).isRequired,
  showImageModifiers: PropTypes.bool,
  thumbnailWidth: PropTypes.string,
  thumbnailHeight: PropTypes.string,
  renderImageFunc: PropTypes.func,
  renderDescriptionFunc: PropTypes.func
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i tried it but this is not working it showing just a blank placeholder

Comment: Are you sure the path to your file is correct? Can you give an example of your folder tree?

Comment: Yes im sure because when i use just some random <img src:{img1}/> tag it works but when i put it into the js code it does not, also here is my tree import img1 from'../../assets/img/vizualizacie/vizualizacie1.jpeg';

Comment: But when i have a link there like: src: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/73/Pyroclastic_flows_at_Mayon_Volcano.jpg', it works

Comment: Ok hmm how about posting the Lightbox component js? You may be referencing the props wrong.

Comment: how are you building your app ? Using webpack ? Do you have the `url-loader` or `file-loader` in your build config ?

Comment: No I'm using gulp

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the image URL as being "domain relative" (i.e. from the current website) by starting it with a single forward slash. For example

```
/my_images/image.png
```

Just pass in a string of that format as the `src` attribute.

Comment: Thanks for an answer, so it should look like this ? src: '/./../../assets/img/vizualizacie/vizualizacie1.jpeg',

Comment: Yeah, as long as that image exists. The `/.` part at the beginning is redundant.